# Why does Bermuda always address characters as -kun?

Tags: japanese-language, reborn

In the manga of *Katekyo Hitman Reborn!* (also commonly just "Reborn!" for obvious reasons) after the future and Shimon Arc ends, the Arcabaleno Arc begins and reveals that:

> Bermuda, the arcobaleno of the eighth element of night, bargains with Reborn in Chapter 384-ish to take his life for future generations and use his life to kill Checker Face.

While reading it, I noticed Bermuda calls *all* characters "-kun"! Since it's obviously a term more for guys, and yet it was used on Chrome and weaker players like Lal Mirch etc., I thought it was a little strange. I don't think it's a translation error either - since 「―くん」is pretty obviously "-kun".

Is there any explanation for this? Is it something to do with his personality?

Comment: please edit your question, the spoiler tag should be used a single >! on a new line before the spoiler, see http://anime.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @grasshopper I suggested the edit.

Comment: Gah! Thank you! I saw so confused. I've been spamming forums way too much! ^3^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case I believe Bermuda is looking down on all the characters as if they were his subordinates or just addressing in an [endearing sense](http://www.japan-talk.com/jt/new/chan-and-kun-in-japanese) (he is *way* older than them).

In company or school situations in Japan "-kun" is by superiors when addressing subordinates of both genders. Alternatively "-kun" might also be used as a term of endearment towards the (younger) male characters (similar to "-chan" with females).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I wasn't aware the -kun was used in such a way :)

Answer (score 5):

This is usually misunderstood by a beginner in Japanese language. It is generally taught that *-kun* is used with men while *-chan* with girls. But, in real usage, this is not always the case.

In fact, Japanese suffix are not used according to genders but personal relationships. *-kun* is used with a junior person to show endearment. For *-chan*, it is to show intimacy but there are nuances that I cannot explain in words as well.